# Rails caching a paginated collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, pagination, russian-doll-caching

Just doing some research on the best way to cache a paginated collection of items. Currently using jbuilder to output JSON and have been playing with various cache_key options.

The best example I've seen is by using the latest record's updated_at plus the amount of items in the collection.

```
def cache_key
      pluck("COUNT(*)", "MAX(updated_at)").flatten.map(&:to_i).join("-")
end
```

defined here: https://gist.github.com/aaronjensen/6062912

However this won't work for paginated items, where I always have 10 items in my collection.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a paginated collection, you're just getting an array. Any attempt to monkey patch Array to include a cache key would be a bit convoluted. Your best bet it just to use the cache method to generate a key on a collection-to-collection basis.

You can pass plenty of things to the cache method to generate a key. If you always have 10 items per page, I don't think the count is very valuable. However, the page number, and the last updated item would be.

```
cache ["v1/items_list/page-#{params[:page]}", @items.maximum('updated_at')] do
```

would generate a cache key like

```
v1/items_list/page-3/20140124164356774568000
```

With russian doll caching you should also cache each item in the list

```
# index.html.erb
<%= cache ["v1/items_list/page-#{params[:page]}", @items.maximum('updated_at')] do %>
  <!-- v1/items_list/page-3/20140124164356774568000 -->
  <%= render @items %>
<% end %>

# _item.html.erb
<%= cache ['v1', item] do %>
  <!-- v1/items/15-20140124164356774568000 -->
  <!-- render item -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: You might also add a session key, user_id, etc. and hash the key into a digest.

Comment: What if an item in the middle gets updated? The parent container in index.html.erb won't know about it right?

Comment: That's part of Russian Doll Caching. DHH [talks about it here](http://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) in #5.

Comment: Hi @JacobEvanShreve, what if the item doesn't belong to everything? Like a list of paginated users for example.

Comment: That's what `@items.max_by(&:updated_at)` is for. If any of the users in that particular paginated segment have been updated, the collection will re-render. This does, though, also depend on the type of paginated list. For example, if this is a search based on an infinitely unique string, you may not want to cache the collection, but rather just the individuals.

Comment: It works well only with simple lists, when we have list of a products, which have images from child model and we want to expire the product cache when his image is updated, this approach can take a long piece of code :)

Comment: Actually the count is invaluable: Image an item being destroyed. That would not change the maximum of `updated_at`, nevertheless at least one of the pages just became invalid. Have a look at `cache_key_for_products` on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching

Comment: `@items.max_by(&:updated_at)` will fetch the items from database anyway and will also process them one by one in ruby. i think it would be better if we used `@items.maximum('updated_at')` which will fetch only the count directly from database.

Answer (score 3):

Caching pagination collections is tricky. The usual trick of using the collection count and max `updated_at` does mostly not apply!

As you said, the collection count is a given so kind of useless, unless you allow dynamic `per_page` values.

The latest `updated_at` is totally dependent on the sorting of your collection.

Imagine than a new record is added and ends up in page one. This means that one record, previously page 1, now enters page 2. One previous page 2 record now becomes page 3. If the new page 2 record is not updated more recently than the previous max, the cache key stays the same but the collection is not! The same happens when a record is deleted.

Only if you can guarantee that new records always end up on the last page and no records will ever be deleted, using the max `updated_at` is a solid way to go.

As a solution, you could include the total record count and the total max `updated_at` in the cache key, in addition to page number and the `per page` value. This will require extra queries, but can be worth it, depending on your database configuration and record count.

Another solution is using a key that takes into account some reduced form of the actual collection content. For example, also taking into account all record id's.

If you are using postgres as a database, this gem might help you, though I've never used it myself.
https://github.com/cmer/scope_cache_key

And the rails 4 fork:
https://github.com/joshblour/scope_cache_key